# Python 2.7.9 xlwings Workbook.save() error

Tags: python, xlwings

I'm getting the following error -

> File "Pyxl_open.py", line 23, in  wb.save AttributeError:
>   'Workbook' object has no attribute 'save'

Python 2.7.9

xlwings installed from pip last week should be xlwings 0.3.2

Windows 7 Pro SP1

Code snippet:

---

```
import xlwings

from xlwings import Workbook, Sheet, Range, Chart

print "xlwings version = ", xlwings.__version__

wb = Workbook('C:\Users\xx\Documents\testxx.csv')

Sheet(1).autofit() 

Sheet(1).add()

wb.save()
```

---

Output:

> xlwings version =  0.3.0
>
> Traceback (most recent call last):
>
> File "xlwing_test.py", line 13, in 
>       wb.save() AttributeError: 'Workbook' object has no attribute 'save'

Is 0.3.0 the problem ?

should I try ?

```
pip uninstall xlwings

pip install xlwings==0.3.2
```

Comment: Please include the relevant code.  Where and how do you define the symbol `Workbook`?

Comment: If you are unsure about the version, do: `import xlwings` and `xlwings.__version__`

Comment: With `pip`, you can also just do `pip install --upgrade xlwings`

Answer (score 1):

I just had this same problem on a recent install of Anaconda.  I had xlwings 0.2.2  "conda update xlwings" updated to 0.3.2, and save now works.

Comment: Yes, this has been added in v0.3.2 only - I ll make sure to update the docs to show the "new in version x.y.z" in the future.